# How to read or save the email of the user when he logged in to facebook through asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm totally blank in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you are authorized to get the user's email with the **email** permission.

Here's an example using the [Branches FB API](http://fbapi.blogspot.com):

```
Dim FB As New SessionInfo("[access_token]")
Dim Req = New Functions.Requests(FB)
Dim U = Req.GetUserInfo()
Response.Write(U.email)
```